# Буква Ґ в русском этимологическом словаре

Tags: орфоэпия

Что обозначает буква Ґ (с верхним хвостиком) в русском этимологическом словаре Фасмера?
Она очень часто встречается у него, например, в словах: Ахинеґя, Аґхти, Аґще и мн. других.

Надо ли эту букву произносить?

Comment: Вот, посмотрите здесь: http://fasmerbook.com/p024.htm

Может и вправду у меня что-то со шрифтом?

Answer (score 2):

Это у вас так знак ударения воспроизводится.
Или у вас шрифт слетел, или на сайте настройки сбились.
Ничем не могу помочь, ибо не знаю источника вашего Фасмера

Comment: Вот, посмотрите здесь: http://fasmerbook.com/p024.htm

Может и вправду у меня что-то со шрифтом?

У Вас тоже на экране такие же загнутые "Г"?

Comment: >Может и вправду у меня что-то со шрифтом?  
    
Ничего не могу сказать. Я на тот сайт минут двадцать ломился - не пускает.    
Но поскольку это проявляется даже при копипастинге (как в вашем вопросе), то скорее всего это проблема сайта.    
Что-то очень похожее происходило на старлинге. Поскольку это первый источник оригинального Фасмера в рунете (они еще в начале 2000-х выложили), то думаю, что ваш источник может быть клоном старлинга и причина та же. Там используется ли очень старая, то ли очень хитрая кодировка и Юникод её не понимает.  
Я не знаю, как с этим бороться.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

В словаре Фасмера этот знак означает ударение на предыдущем слоге. Не путать с похожей по графике украин. буквой для взрывного Г.